How to combine two indicators in Traidingview (Pine Editor)
Traidingview has an indicator called "Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LuxAlgo]". I want to run this indicator two at a time.
This is the normal way of working
I want it to look like this
Indicator original codes
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo

//@version=5
indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LuxAlgo]", "LuxAlgo - Nadaraya-Watson Envelope", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back=500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
h = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth', minval = 0)
mult = input.float(3., minval = 0)
src = input(close, 'Source')

repaint = input(true, 'Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = 'Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')

//Style
upCss = input.color(color.teal, 'Colors', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')
dnCss = input.color(color.red, '', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Gaussian window
gauss(x, h) => math.exp(-(math.pow(x, 2)/(h * h * 2)))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Append lines
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
n = bar_index

var ln = array.new_line(0) 

if barstate.isfirst and repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//End point method
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var coefs = array.new_float(0)
var den = 0.

if barstate.isfirst and not repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        w = gauss(i, h)
        coefs.push(w)

    den := coefs.sum()

out = 0.
if not repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        out += src[i] * coefs.get(i)
out /= den
mae = ta.sma(math.abs(src - out), 499) * mult

upper = out + mae
lower = out - mae
 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Compute and display NWE
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
float y2 = na
float y1 = na

nwe = array.new<float>(0)
if barstate.islast and repaint
    sae = 0.
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            w = gauss(i - j, h)
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w

        y2 := sum / sumw
        sae += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        nwe.push(y2)
    
    sae := sae / math.min(499,n - 1) * mult
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        if i%2
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 + sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) + sae, color = upCss)
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 - sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) - sae, color = dnCss)
        
        if src[i] > nwe.get(i) + sae and src[i+1] < nwe.get(i) + sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▼', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = dnCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        if src[i] < nwe.get(i) - sae and src[i+1] > nwe.get(i) - sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▲', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = upCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        
        y1 := nwe.get(i)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Dashboard
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var tb = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1
  , bgcolor = #1e222d
  , border_color = #373a46
  , border_width = 1
  , frame_color = #373a46
  , frame_width = 1)

if repaint
    tb.cell(0, 0, 'Repainting Mode Enabled', text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plot
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
plot(repaint ? na : out + mae, 'Upper', upCss)
plot(repaint ? na : out - mae, 'Lower', dnCss)

//Crossing Arrows
plotshape(ta.crossunder(close, out - mae) ? low : na, "Crossunder", shape.labelup, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▲', textcolor = upCss, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ta.crossover(close, out + mae) ? high : na, "Crossover", shape.labeldown, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▼', textcolor = dnCss, size = size.tiny)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

Some code blocks I tried to run
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo

//@version=5
indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [TRYYY]", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back=500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
h = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth', minval = 0)
mult = input.float(3.,'Mult', minval = 0)
src = input(close, 'Source')

h2 = input.float(7.,'Bandwidth2', minval = 0)
mult2 = input.float(2.,'Mult2', minval = 0)
src2 = input(close, 'Source2')

repaint = input(true, 'Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = 'Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')

repaint2 = input(true, '2 Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = '2 Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')

//Style
upCss = input.color(color.teal, 'Colors1', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')
dnCss = input.color(color.red, '', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')

upCss2 = input.color(color.rgb(55, 208, 255), 'Colors2', inline = 'inline2', group = 'Style2')
dnCss2 = input.color(color.rgb(253, 134, 36), '', inline = 'inline2', group = 'Style2')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Functions
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//Gaussian window
gauss(x, h) => math.exp(-(math.pow(x, 2)/(h * h * 2)))
gauss2(x2, h2) => math.exp(-(math.pow(x2, 2)/(h2 * h2 * 2)))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Append lines
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
n = bar_index

n2 = bar_index

var ln = array.new_line(0) 

var ln2 = array.new_line(0) 

if barstate.isfirst and repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))

if barstate.isfirst and repaint2
    for i2 = 0 to 499
        array.push(ln2,line.new(na,na,na,na))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//End point method
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var coefs = array.new_float(0)
var den = 0.

var coefs2 = array.new_float(0)
var den2 = 0.

if barstate.isfirst and not repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        w = gauss(i, h)
        coefs.push(w)

    den := coefs.sum()

if barstate.isfirst and not repaint2
    for i2 = 0 to 499
        w2 = gauss2(i2, h2)
        coefs2.push(w2)

    den2 := coefs2.sum()

out = 0.
if not repaint
    for i = 0 to 499
        out += src[i] * coefs.get(i)
out /= den
mae = ta.sma(math.abs(src - out), 499) * mult

out2 = 0.
if not repaint2
    for i2 = 0 to 499
        out2 += src2[i2] * coefs2.get(i2)
out2 /= den2
mae2 = ta.sma(math.abs(src2 - out2), 499) * mult2

upper = out + mae
lower = out - mae

upper2 = out2 + mae2
lower2 = out2 - mae2
 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Compute and display NWE
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
float y2 = na
float y1 = na

float y22 = na
float y12 = na

nwe = array.new<float>(0)
if barstate.islast and repaint
    sae = 0.
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            w = gauss(i - j, h)
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w

        y2 := sum / sumw
        sae += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        nwe.push(y2)
    
    sae := sae / math.min(499,n - 1) * mult
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        if i%2
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 + sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) + sae, color = upCss)
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 - sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) - sae, color = dnCss)
        
        if src[i] > nwe.get(i) + sae and src[i+1] < nwe.get(i) + sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▼', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = dnCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        if src[i] < nwe.get(i) - sae and src[i+1] > nwe.get(i) - sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▲', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = upCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        
        y1 := nwe.get(i)

nwe2 = array.new<float>(0)
if barstate.islast and repaint2
    sae2 = 0.
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i2 = 0 to math.min(499,n2 - 1)
        sum2 = 0.
        sumw2 = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j2 = 0 to math.min(499,n2 - 1)
            w2 = gauss2(i2 - j2, h2)
            sum2 += src2[j2] * w2
            sumw2 += w2

        y22 := sum2 / sumw2
        sae2 += math.abs(src2[i2] - y22)
        nwe2.push(y22)
    
    sae2 := sae2 / math.min(499,n2 - 1) * mult2
    for i2 = 0 to math.min(499,n2 - 1)
        if i2%2
            line.new(n2-i2+1, y12 + sae2, n2-i2, nwe2.get(i2) + sae2, color = upCss2)
            line.new(n2-i2+1, y12 - sae2, n2-i2, nwe2.get(i2) - sae2, color = dnCss2)
        
        if src2[i2] > nwe2.get(i2) + sae2 and src2[i2+1] < nwe2.get(i2) + sae2
            label.new(n2-i2, src2[i2], '▼', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = dnCss2, textalign = text.align_center)
        if src2[i2] < nwe2.get(i2) - sae2 and src2[i2+1] > nwe2.get(i2) - sae2
            label.new(n2-i2, src2[i2], '▲', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = upCss2, textalign = text.align_center)
        
        y12 := nwe2.get(i2)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Dashboard
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
//

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plot
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
pu1 = plot(repaint ? na : out + mae, 'Upper1', upCss)
pl1 = plot(repaint ? na : out - mae, 'Lower1', dnCss)

pu2 = plot(repaint2 ? na : out2 + mae2, 'Upper2', upCss2)
pl2 = plot(repaint2 ? na : out2 - mae2, 'Lower2', dnCss2)


fill(pl1, pu2, color=color.rgb(26, 241, 33))

//Crossing Arrows
plotshape(ta.crossunder(close, out - mae) ? low : na, "Crossunder1", shape.labelup, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▲', textcolor = upCss, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ta.crossover(close, out + mae) ? high : na, "Crossover1", shape.labeldown, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▼', textcolor = dnCss, size = size.tiny)

plotshape(ta.crossunder(close, out2 - mae2) ? low : na, "Crossunder2", shape.labelup, location.absolute, color(na), 1 , text = '▲', textcolor = upCss2, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ta.crossover(close, out2 + mae2) ? high : na, "Crossover2", shape.labeldown, location.absolute, color(na), 1 , text = '▼', textcolor = dnCss2, size = size.tiny)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo

//@version=5
indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LuxAlgo]", "LuxAlgo - Nadaraya-Watson Envelope", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500, max_bars_back=500)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Settings
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
h = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth', minval = 0)
mult = input.float(3., minval = 0)
src = input(close, 'Source')

h2 = input.float(7.,'Bandwidth2', minval = 0)
mult2 = input.float(2., minval = 0)
src2 = input(close, 'Source2')

repaint = input(true, 'Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = 'Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')
repaint2 = input(true, '2 Repainting Smoothing', tooltip = '2 Repainting is an effect where the indicators historical output is subject to change over time. Disabling repainting will cause the indicator to output the endpoints of the calculations')

//Style

upCss = input.color(color.teal, 'Colors', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')
dnCss = input.color(color.red, '', inline = 'inline1', group = 'Style')

upCss2 = input.color(color.teal, 'Colors2', inline = 'inline2', group = 'Style2')
dnCss2 = input.color(color.red, '', inline = 'inline2', group = 'Style2')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

indi1(h, mult, src, repaint, upCss, dnCss) =>

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    //Functions
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
    //Gaussian window
    //gauss(x, h) => math.exp(-(math.pow(x, 2)/(h * h * 2)))

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    //Append lines
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
    n = bar_index

    var ln = array.new_line(0) 

    if barstate.isfirst and repaint
        for i = 0 to 499
            array.push(ln,line.new(na,na,na,na))

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    //End point method
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
    var coefs = array.new_float(0)
    var den = 0.

    if barstate.isfirst and not repaint
        for i = 0 to 499
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i, 2)/(h * h * 2)))
            coefs.push(w)

        den := coefs.sum()

    out = 0.
    if not repaint
        for i = 0 to 499
            out += src[i] * coefs.get(i)
    out /= den
    mae = ta.sma(math.abs(src - out), 499) * mult

    upper = out + mae
    lower = out - mae
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    //Compute and display NWE
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
    float y2 = na
    float y1 = na

    nwe = array.new<float>(0)
    if barstate.islast and repaint
        sae = 0.
        //Compute and set NWE point 
        for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            sum = 0.
            sumw = 0.
            //Compute weighted mean 
            for j = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
                x = i - j
                w = math.exp(-(math.pow(x, 2)/(h * h * 2)))
                sum += src[j] * w
                sumw += w

            y2 := sum / sumw
            sae += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
            nwe.push(y2)
        
        sae := sae / math.min(499,n - 1) * mult
        for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            if i%2
                line.new(n-i+1, y1 + sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) + sae, color = upCss)
                line.new(n-i+1, y1 - sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) - sae, color = dnCss)
            
            if src[i] > nwe.get(i) + sae and src[i+1] < nwe.get(i) + sae
                label.new(n-i, src[i], '▼', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = dnCss, textalign = text.align_center)
            if src[i] < nwe.get(i) - sae and src[i+1] > nwe.get(i) - sae
                label.new(n-i, src[i], '▲', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = upCss, textalign = text.align_center)
            
            y1 := nwe.get(i)

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    //Dashboard
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
    var tb = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1, bgcolor = #1e222d, border_color = #373a46, border_width = 1, frame_color = #373a46, frame_width = 1)

    if repaint
        tb.cell(0, 0, 'Repainting Mode Enabled', text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)

    [out, mae]

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plot
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

[out, mae] = indi1(h, mult, src, repaint, upCss, dnCss)
[out2, mae2] = indi1(h2, mult2, src2, repaint2, upCss2, dnCss2)

//

plot(repaint ? na : out + mae, 'Upper', upCss)
plot(repaint ? na : out - mae, 'Lower', dnCss)


//Crossing Arrows

//plotshape(ta.crossunder(close, out - mae) ? low : na, "Crossunder", shape.labelup, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▲', textcolor = upCss, size = size.tiny)
//plotshape(ta.crossover(close, out + mae) ? high : na, "Crossover", shape.labeldown, location.absolute, color(na), 0 , text = '▼', textcolor = dnCss, size = size.tiny)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

I didn't succeed, unfortunately. :/ The lines overlap and behave as a single line
